# Check whether any value is zero using jq and return 0 to the calling shell script

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

I have this JSON file:

{
    "key11":1010,
    "key12":12120,
    "key13":12103
   }

How can I use `jq` to check whether any of the values corresponding to a `key[0-9][0-9]` are zero, making `jq` exit successfully if any is and not otherwise?

I have this script from a previous question

```
#!/bin/bash
json=$(cat <<EOF
{"key11":12120,"key11_":13,"key11_yes":12107,
"key12":13492,"key12_no":9,"key12_yes":13483,
"key13":10200,"key13_no":9,"key13_yes":10191,
"key21":16756,"key21_no":30,"key21_yes":16726,
"key22":17057,"key22_no":34,"key22_yes":17023,
"key23":16798,"key23_no":25,"key23_yes":16773,
"key31":2733,"key31_yes":2733,
"key32":2561,"key32_yes":2561,
"key33":2570,"key33_yes":2570}
EOF
)
json2=$(echo ${json}|jq 'with_entries(if (.key|test("key[0-9][0-9]$")) then ( {key: .key, value: .value } ) else empty end )')
```

The result is:

```
{ "key11": 12120, "key12": 13492, "key13": 10200, "key21": 16756, "key22": 17057, "key23": 16798, "key31": 2733, "key32": 2561, "key33": 2570 }
```

Now I want check the value attached to all keys in `$json2`, and then if the value of *any* of the entries is zero return `0`.

Comment: What does "value keys are zero" mean?

Comment: You seem to have an existing script, could you please share it with us so that we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: e.g : `{
   "key11":1010,
   "key12":12120,
   "key13":12103,
   "key14": 0
  }`
If the value of each of the keys is zero, script return `0` status.

Comment: @pyramid13, elaborate your condition: it should return `0` if ANY of keys is `0`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, The script was shared :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes  return 0 if ANY of keys is 0.

Comment: That's [not what](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444755/bash-script-and-process-json-format-by-jq-tools/444759#comment805914_444755) you [asked for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/444755/2) (twice).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`any` is a built-in filter that returns true if any item is true](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)), and false otherwise. [`--exit-status`/`-e` causes `jq` to exit `0`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Invokingjq) iff the last output is neither false nor null.

If you've already winnowed the document down to just the keys you care about like in your script, you can just do this:

```
previous_command | jq -e 'any( .[] ; . == 0 )'
```

`.[]` pulls all the values out, and `any` will output true only if it finds a zero in them. Alternatively, `[.[]|.==0]|any` or `map(.==0) | any`; pick whichever one you find clearest.

---

You can also do the whole thing in one go, saving a wasted `jq` process:

```
jq -e '[to_entries | .[] | select(.key | test("key[0-9][0-9]$")) | .value == 0 ] | any' data.json
```

This selects all the matching keys and checks whether each value is 0, then pipes the collection of results through `any`, thus exiting 0 if there were any zeros. If you're sure there are no NaNs you could also multiply them all together with [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Reduce).

Comment: If we want to look at the exact format of a keys, what should we do? i use `json2=$(echo ${json}|jq -e '[to_entries | .[] | (.key | test("key[0-9][0-9]$"))] | any ')`
but return true even if we have only `key`.

Comment: @pyramid13, important to quote the variable: `echo "$json"` not `echo ${json}`. To illustrate, set `json="foo * bar"` and try the 2 echo commands.

Comment: @Michael Homer, please look my [qustion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444915/process-json-format-with-jq-tools?noredirect=1#comment806339_444915)